# Can I 'enumerate' with Rust's variadic macros?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Essentially I have a macro that looks like:

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
  ( $expr:expr; $( $pat:pat ),* ) => {
    match $expr {
      $(
        $pat => $(some-macro-magic-here),
      )*
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything that can go into `$(some-macro-magic-here)`, so that

```rust
my_macro!(foo; A, B, C)
```

will expand to

```rust
match foo {
  A => 2,
  B => 4,
  C => 6,
}
```

?

Is there some other way I might be able to get a similar feature that effectively lets me "enumerate" over the sequence of inputs for the macro?

I think I could probably write a recursive macro to get a similar effect, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant/idiomatic way about it than what I'm thinking of

Answer (score 2):

Because macros aren't allowed to store or manipulate "variables" in any form, this problem becomes very difficult. You could, however, use an iterator to do something to the same effect, by creating an iterator that "enumerates" over the input the way you want it (using [`std::iter::successors`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.successors.html), for example), and simply calling `iterator.next().unwrap()` in `$(some-macro-magic-here)`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create such `match` statement as Rust do not allow creating `match` branches via macro, aka this will not work right now:

```rust
match val {
    my_macro! (A, B, C)
}
```

However in this case we can "hack it around" by using nested `if let` blocks and using recursive macro:

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
  ($expr:expr; $($pat:pat),*) => {
    my_macro!($expr; 2, 2; $($pat),*)
  };
  ($expr:expr; $curr:expr, $step:literal; $pat:pat) => {
    if let $pat = $expr {
        $curr
    } else {
        unreachable!()
    }
  };
  ($expr:expr; $curr:expr, $step:literal; $pat:pat, $($rest:pat),*) => {
    if let $pat = $expr {
        $curr
    } else {
        my_macro! ($expr; $curr+$step, $step; $($rest),*)
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95cb825e63031e40ce20863083a574b1)

It will generate the nested entries with enough `2` added to create the expected constants. Alternatively you could replace that with multiplication, but it should be optimised out by the compiler anyway.